# substr() function for array PHP

Tags: php, substr, implode

I have a code that will produce array of strings.... now my problem is i need to substr each result of the array but i think array is not allowed to be used in substr...

please help:

CODE:

```
<?php
$file = 'upload/filter.txt';
$searchfor = $_POST['search'];
$btn = $_POST['button'];
$sum = 0;

if($btn == 'search') {

//prevents the browser from parsing this as HTML.
header('Content-Type: text/plain');

// get the file contents, assuming the file to be readable (and exist)
$contents = file_get_contents($file);

// escape special characters in the query
$pattern = preg_quote($searchfor, '/');

// finalise the regular expression, matching the whole line
$pattern = "/^.*$pattern.*\$/m";


// search, and store all matching occurences in $matches
if(preg_match_all($pattern, $contents, $matches)){
echo "Found matches:\n";
$result = implode("\n", $matches[0]);
echo $result;


 }
else{
 echo "No matches found";
 }


 }
 ?>
```

The $matches there is the array... i need to substr each result of the $matches

Comment: To apply a function to all items in an array use `array_map` (returns a new array) or `array_walk` (can mutate items in the original array).

Comment: first thing your question is not clear, On which array you to use substr. Have you tried? . Good solution for any array to apply function is array_map

Comment: hi @Jon thanks for your reply... can you give a sample code if you dont mind :3

Comment: @BOSS i need to substr each result of the $matches array...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use [`array_walk`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php):

```
function fcn(&$item) {
   $item = substr(..do what you want here ...);
}

array_walk($matches, "fcn");
```

Comment: can i put my $matches array in the substr? I need to substr each result of the array @matches

Comment: @Bongsky, no you cannot put `$matches` in `substr`. You have to walk over the array and apply substr to each individual element. To example I gave you will update the `$matches` array.

Comment: it does nothing... as ive known substr has 1st parameter string... what would be my parameters?

Comment: @Bongsky in the `fcn` function in my example, `$item` holds the value of each item, so your call would be something like `$item = substr($item, 5);` or so.

Comment: i get this error sir... substr() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

Answer (score 3):

Proper use of array_walk

```
array_walk( $matches, substr(your area));
```

Array_map accepts several arrays

```
array_map(substr(your area),  $matches1, $origarray2);
```

in your case

```
 array_map(substr(your area),  $matches);
```

Read more:

[array_map](http://php.net/array_map)

[array_walk](http://php.net/array_walk)

Comment: what does your area implies? what are the parameters?

Answer (score 0):

To find a sub string in an array I use this function on a production site, works perfectly.

I convert the array to a collection because it's easier to manage.

```
public function substrInArray($substr, Array $array) {
    $substr = strtolower($substr);
    $array = collect($array); // convert array to collection

    return $body_types->map(function ($array_item) {
        return strtolower($array_item);
    })->filter(function ($array_item) use ($substr) {
        return substr_count($array_item, $substr);
    })->keys()->first();

}
```

This will return the key from the first match, it's just an example you can tinker. Returns `null` if nothing found.